# Is there a way to specify a required definition for template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Am I allowed to write this syntax:

```
template <class T{public :SDL_Rect getRect() const; }>
```

This is to make sure that template argument will have  `SDL_Rect getRect() const`

However I am getting `error: unexpected Type "T"`. Any suggestions if I am making a mistake on the syntax or if this isn't allowed at all?

Comment: Short answer: **No!** What do you actually want to achieve? Class type lambda expressions?

Comment: If you're doing this to attempt to limit what kinds of types the template will work with, then that's not quite a way to do it. Just attempt to use getRect() from within the template and the compiler will enforce that for you with errors.

Comment: wow!...what's the reason behind instant down-votes?

Comment: @N_E _"what's the reason behind instant down-votes?"_ Because that's an extraordinary stupid question. Of course the syntax isn't allowed, hence the compiler complains about it. Again, please explain what do you want to achieve with that kind of syntax. Looks like you're asking for a XY-problem.

Comment: @N_E It turns out from answers, that the term _template class_ as you use it is unclear in particular. Did you mean to constrain some _template parameter_ actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is actually a very good question about concepts, even if OP guessed the syntax wrong.

Comment: @o11c Well, your edits are borderline. I'd prefer if the OP gets in and assure what they actually mean.

Comment: "This is to make sure that template argument will have  SDL_Rect getRect() const" was in the original and is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @o11c _"... was in the original and is pretty clear to me."_ That's not true. T.C. changed _class_ to _argument_ in previous edits.

Comment: I apologize for inferring my question the way i did. It is because intellisense was not highlighting it as an error, and I disregarded the compilation error  because i am fighting class forwarding errors so as usual i am not being told  the exact errors. Also I was hoping someone would point me to a right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With concepts:

```
template<class T>
    requires requires(const T t) {
        { t.getRect() } -> SDL_Rect;
    }
class Meow { };
```

This checks that `t.getRect()` is implicitly convertible to `SDL_Rect`. To check for exact match,

```
template<class T, class U> concept bool Same = std::is_same_v<T, U>;

template<class T>
    requires requires(const T t) {
        { t.getRect() } -> Same<SDL_Rect>;
    }
class Meow { };
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is to make sure that template class will have `SDL_Rect getRect()` const

If you write something like

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
    void foo() {
        T t;
        SDL_Rect r = t.getRect();
    }
};
```

the compiler will already complain if `T` doesn't provide the `SDL_Rect getRect()` function.

---

If you want to have better compiler error messages you can use a [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::getRect)>::value,
                  "T must implement the SDL_Rect getRect() const function");
    void foo() {
        T t;
        SDL_Rect r = t.getRect();
    }
};
```

Comment: @T.C. THX for pointing out, fixed. I'm still looking after a better constraint check to match the exact function signature, do you have a easy and straightforward proposal?

Comment: For exact signature, just add a `static_cast<SDL_Rect (T::*)() const>` on top? Not a big fan though, since that disallows `SDL_Rect getRect(int = 0) const;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::is_same` with `decltype`?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> This is to make sure that template class will have  `SDL_Rect getRect() const`

You have some of the syntactic elements in the wrong place to accomplish that.

The code you are looking for is:

```
template <class T> class MyClass
{
   public :
      SDL_Rect getRect() const;
};
```

Comment: You're not giving the class a name.  Would that compile?

Comment: @BobC, no it wouldn't.

Comment: @RSahu Not sure if the OP's really asking about this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, do you suppose he expects the template parameter to be a class that has `SDL_Rect getRect() const;`?

Comment: @RSahu Yup, exactly. See the cite on my answer. I think that _template class_ was confused with _template parameter_ actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Let's hope one of us covered the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has already answered your question:  No, it is not allowed.

You're not declaring a template there anyway.  It looks like you're trying to declare a template class, but the syntax is all wrong.

Most likely, you just need to spend some time learning about templates, i.e. a site like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm or a good book.